# ASP.Net Add data if data does not exist, if data exist then update data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I am  trying to create program when data already exist, it will update data, If no then it will add data, below is my code.. Update is working but the add is not working. If I remove the update code then the add will work

```
            var itemLocQuantity = objERPMicroDbEntities.ItemLocationDatas.FirstOrDefault(items => items.ItemId == item.ItemId && items.LocationId == item.LocationId);

            if (itemLocQuantity.ItemId == item.ItemId && itemLocQuantity.LocationId == item.LocationId) {
                itemLocQuantity.Quantity += item.QuantityReceive;

            }
```

Above is the update

```
            if (itemLocQuantity == null)
            {
                itemLocQuantity = new ItemLocationData();
                // create new in db
                itemLocQuantity.ItemId = item.ItemId;
                itemLocQuantity.Quantity = item.QuantityReceive;
                itemLocQuantity.LocationId = item.LocationId;
                objERPMicroDbEntities.ItemLocationDatas.Add(itemLocQuantity);

            }
```

Above is the code trying to add but my program is returning error when trying to add new data

Comment: Could you explain what the error is

Answer (score 0):

If your whole function looks like this:

```
 var itemLocQuantity = objERPMicroDbEntities.ItemLocationDatas.FirstOrDefault(items => items.ItemId == item.ItemId && items.LocationId == item.LocationId);

if (itemLocQuantity.ItemId == item.ItemId && itemLocQuantity.LocationId == item.LocationId) 
{
    itemLocQuantity.Quantity += item.QuantityReceive;
}

if (itemLocQuantity == null)
{
    itemLocQuantity = new ItemLocationData();
    // create new in db
    itemLocQuantity.ItemId = item.ItemId;
    itemLocQuantity.Quantity = item.QuantityReceive;
    itemLocQuantity.LocationId = item.LocationId;
    objERPMicroDbEntities.ItemLocationDatas.Add(itemLocQuantity);
}
```

Then the issue when you go to insert will be that your update code expects an object to be returned, which will fail because it happens before the Null check. You can reverse the conditions and use an `else` condition for the update:

```
 var itemLocQuantity = objERPMicroDbEntities.ItemLocationDatas.SingleOrDefault(items => items.ItemId == item.ItemId && items.LocationId == item.LocationId);

if (itemLocQuantity == null) // insert.
{
    itemLocQuantity = new ItemLocationData();
    // create new in db
    itemLocQuantity.ItemId = item.ItemId;
    itemLocQuantity.Quantity = item.QuantityReceive;
    itemLocQuantity.LocationId = item.LocationId;
    objERPMicroDbEntities.ItemLocationDatas.Add(itemLocQuantity);
} 
else  // update.
{
    itemLocQuantity.Quantity += item.QuantityReceive;
}
```

This can even be condensed down to:

```
 var itemLocQuantity = objERPMicroDbEntities.ItemLocationDatas.SingleOrDefault(items => items.ItemId == item.ItemId && items.LocationId == item.LocationId);

if (itemLocQuantity == null) // insert.
{
    itemLocQuantity = new ItemLocationData();
    // create new in db
    itemLocQuantity.ItemId = item.ItemId;
    itemLocQuantity.LocationId = item.LocationId;
    objERPMicroDbEntities.ItemLocationDatas.Add(itemLocQuantity);
} 

itemLocQuantity.Quantity += item.QuantityReceive;
```

If we don't find an item, insert it, then after it is added, or if it already exists, update the update-able fields outside of the `if`.

Also, if you are querying and expecting one or zero items, use `SingleOrDefault` rather than `FirstOrDefault`. `First*` methods imply I expect zero or multiple, and I only care about the first match. They should always use an `OrderBy*` clause to ensure the results are repeatable.

Comment: Thank you so much Steve for the solution as well as the tips!! It worked!! .. Been trying to solve this for hours :D